# Proving properties of stream functions in Idris

Tags: stream, idris, dependent-type, frp

I'm trying to prove properties about stream functions and Monadic Stream Functions [1] (and ultimately, FRP programs).

Idris is happy with my formalization of stream functions:

```
module SF

import Data.Vect
import Syntax.PreorderReasoning

%default total

data SF : Type -> Type -> Type where
  SFG : (a -> (b, Inf (SF a b))) -> SF a b

steps : {n : Nat} -> SF a b -> Vect n a -> Vect n b
steps {n = Z}   (SFG s) []        = []
steps {n = S m} (SFG s) (a :: as) =
    let (b, s') = s a
        bs = steps s' as
    in (b::bs)
```

I can trivially define lifting/pointwise application functions:

```
liftM : (a -> b) -> SF a b
liftM f = SFG $ \a => (f a, liftM f)
```

As well as two variants of the identity for SFs:

```
identityM : SF a a
identityM = SFG $ \a => (a, identityM)

identity2 : SF a a
identity2 = liftM id
```

This passes Idris' totality checker. However, if I now try to prove that `identityM` and `identity2` are equal, I run into problems. I can state the property as follows:

```
proof1 :  (Eq b)
       => (n : Nat)
       -> (v : Vect n a)
       -> (steps identityM v) = (steps identity2 v)
proof1 Z [] = ?proof1_rhs_1
proof1 (S k) v = ?proof1_rhs_2
```

If I ask for the type of `?proof1_rhs_1`, idris correctly says `steps identityM [] = steps identity2 []`. However, if I try to use equational reasoning to express just that:

```
proof1 Z [] = (steps {n=Z} identityM []) ={ ?someR }=
              (steps {n=Z} identity2 []) QED
```

Then idris is unhappy:

```
When checking argument x to function Syntax.PreorderReasoning.Equal.qed:
        Type mismatch between
                steps identity2 [] (Inferred value)
        and
                steps identity2 [] (Given value)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        steps identity2
                and
                        []Unification failure
```

Is there any way to make this work?

[1] https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2976010

Answer (score 3):

It's the usual "Idris' implicit generalization makes for confusing scoping rules":

```
proof1 :  (Eq b)
       => (n : Nat)
       -> (v : Vect n a)
       -> (steps identityM v) = (steps identity2 v)
```

means

```
proof1 : {identityM : _} -> {identity2 : _} -> (...)
       -> (steps identityM v) = (steps identity2 v)
```

To refer to the previous definitions, you need to use qualified names `SF.identityM` and `SF.identity2`. You probably have other issues (`Eq b` with `b` mentioned nowhere else in the rest of the type seems dubious).

Comment: You're right. However, when I do that, if I expand/pattern match on the constructor for `v`, I get the error:
`Type mismatch between x :: steps (SFG (\a => (a, Delay identityM))) xs = x :: steps (SFG (\a => (a, Delay (liftM id)))) xs and x :: steps identityM xs = x :: steps (liftM id) xs`